# sql not case sensitive query without using upper or lower function

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have following query ,

```
select * from process where name like 'abc';
```

now the name can be abc or ABC  or Abc or aBc , any combination ,

i can not use upper and lower function as this query gets passed to some another system which does not support such functions ,

Also, collate is not supported 
i.e.  i can not do  ,eg .

```
select * from process where name like 'abc' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Is there any way to make this query case-insensitive without using upper and lower functions ?

Comment: Do you have any control on the data in the other database? You might be able to add a column or a whole separate table with the lowercase version of the name column. Otherwise, your options seem quite limited.

Comment: unfortunately that data comes from end user, so i can not touch it but adding a column seems better choice then

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are doing with that string? Oracle sessions can set nls_comp/sort to alter session collation ...

Comment: i have process associated with data, so name is just one data associated with process ,  i need list of processes based on name criteria , i pass this query as a string to system and it returns me list in xml format

Comment: @pradeep Are you able to use a regex?

Comment: i can use %abc% but other regex not supported

Comment: But what is the system you pass the string to? an oracle server? mysql?

Comment: system can use sql server or oracle , we configure data source initially

Comment: Why is this tagged with mysql and not SQL Server if you are using SQL Server and Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can't use:

1. lower or upper
2. assing case insensitive collate

Possibly combining all results:

```
select * from process where name in ('abc', 'aBc', 'ABc', 'aBC', 'abC', 'AbC', 'aBC', 'ABC')
```

Comment: i can not use lower function- this query goes to another system, which validates it parsing the query and allows only limited functionality

Comment: Yes, it's working :) ,so i can create these combinations for given name , this seems one of the better choice then

Comment: So the proble boils down to the fact that the incoming data is not under the management of a real DBMS, and the system that manages it cannot do the transformation you require.  You aren't going to get a good solution here.  The best you are going to get is some table links coupled with some views that create lower (or upper) case versions of the relevant data, coupled with a select on  the views.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
select * from process where name rlike '[aA][bB][cC]'
```

Comment: You should document your answer to let the OP adapt your solution (at his example) to his real code